# Creating an image from a userform of exported charts

Tags: excel, vba, image, userform

I have written a code that charts various data. The charts are then exported as .gif files. The image files are then loaded as pictures into image controls in a userform as shown below.

How do I go about exporting the whole userform (preferably without the 3 buttons on the right) as an image for use in a report?

Currently I am using manual printscreen but it is quite time consuming..

[Chart Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBm9H.jpg)

Currently I am manually using printscreen but it is quite time consuming..
Is there a way to access the alt-printscreen button perhaps?

The chart creation code itself isn't really relevant but I can share if required.

I expect an image file that I can then use within a word document.
Preferably cropped to remove the 3 buttons on the right of the userform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steven,

In the below sub, I used the SendKeys method to send *Alt+PrintScreen* (**"%{1068}"**) and *Ctrl+V* (**"^v"**) on the current application. The SendKeys method simulates the key presses of a keyboard, so it would replicate what you're doing right now.

```
Sub PrintTheScreen()
    Application.SendKeys ("%{1068}")
    DoEvents
    Application.SendKeys ("^v")
    DoEvents
End Sub
```

Reference for this method can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement)

Having the sendkeys applied to the userform will simulate your button press. By then, you could set a word application object and paste the printed screen, for example.

Sub CreatingWDDoc()
    Dim appWD As Word.Application

```
Set appWD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    appWD.Visible = True
    appWD.Documents.Add
    appWD.SendKeys ("^v")
    ' Change the string to the path you wish to use for seving the file
    appWD.SaveAs (“”)
    appWD.Quit
End Sub
```

Keep in mind that to use such functions, you need to have the word library referenced in your project, under *Tools >> References*. More information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/excel/concepts/working-with-other-applications/controlling-one-microsoft-office-application-from-another).

Comment: Thank you  Breno, I actually combined this with a piece of software I use called GreenShot which overrides my printscreen button. 

I can use this program to automatically save screenshots to a defined directory. Combined with your sendkeys method it works a treat!

To remove the 3 buttons on the side I just created a duplicate userform without the buttons for use specifically when exporting.